# Does Heart of Fenrir trigger before parity check victory?

Tags: werewolv.es

If there are only village members legt but someone carries a HoF, does the village win before the HoF carrier becomes an Omegawolf, or not?

Does it matter whether the death of last wolf (and perhaps any other evils) happens because of lynch or because of night kills? Is there a different interaction between HoF and dawn/nightfall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parity check currently happens every 30 seconds, the Heart triggers at nightfall. If the last wolf dies during the night (for example getting Militia shot), the Heart wont trigger and parity will be reached in the morning.